# AuraRuntimeException: no such property: length for String attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Recently our lightning app started failing with a very odd error.

[image]
I've created a very simple lightning app that reproduces that issue. So it looks like `length` property is not available anymore for attributes of `String` type in Winter 20 sandbox.

Is anyone has the same issue? Is it a platform bug or security improvement?

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
<aura:attribute name="sampleString" type="String" default="" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.sampleString.length != 0}">

</aura:if>
```

UPD: After some investigation on different sandboxes. Found out this issue is reproduced only on `Winter 20 Patch 8.6` The same code works fine on `Winter 20 Patch 8.5`

Answer (score 1):

aura:application was not supporting it from last few months. However, it is supposed to be acting ONLY as a container for lightning component(s). So, you should ideally use all the logic in component and use that component in app.

App:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:myComp />
</aura:application>
```

c:myComp:

```
<aura:attribute name="sampleString" type="String" default="asd" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.sampleString.length != 0}">
    sampleString.length != 0
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.sampleString.length == 0}">
    sampleString.length == 0
</aura:if>
```

Comment: that's correct. I've put the code into the lightning app just to simplify steps to reproduce. Originally this error started to appear in the regular aura components.

Comment: Do you have any references why lightning app does not support aura:if syntax?